# Does the nonce have to be a number?

Tags: mining-technical-details, nonce

Since we're just trying to produce a specific hash output, couldn't the nonce also include letters or otherwise random bits?

Comment: it needs to be increasing, so using a number or more specifically a date makes this easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nonce is an arbitrary string of bits with no particular meaning. Typically they are converted into an unsigned integer for convenience. Every possible set of nonce bits has a corresponding integer in this representation.

To get letter in a nonce, you'd have to present the bits in the nonce in some encoding scheme that had some way to encode letters. There is no such scheme in common use.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the nonce is just 4 bytes that are ignored. There's no reason why the block couldn't contain "Nick" in ASCII, or somebody's phone number.

That being said:

1. the fastest way to mine is to start with a nonce of all 0's, then increment it.
2. an easier way to embed data into the blockchain is to use fields in the coinbase.

Comment: So are there any blocks with letters in the nonce? I understand your 2 points, would it increase the probability of solving a block if your miner actually incremented 0-9 then a-z and A-Z, etc?

Comment: @pinhead `So are there any blocks with letters in the nonce?` Probably. [One in every thousand blocks](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2852%2F256%29%5E4) has a nonce of all letters. There are 200 thousand.